# Get more battery time from hp laptop

Tags: hp, battery

i have a HP gamer laptop 15 ([15-dk0008la](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-Pavilion-Gaming-15-dk0000-Laptop-PC/26122224/model/29180010)) with Ubuntu 18.04.

I hardly get 3 hours of battery (the usual are 2 to 2.5 hours) and that is with, Bluetooth off, keyboard back light off and working with the internet browser and some documents.

Installed TLP with its default settings and i didn't noticed any change.

The laptop has:

- i5-9300
- 16 gb ram
- 256 gb ssd
- nvidia gtx 1050
- 3 cells 52,5 WH battery

I know that being a gaming laptop i cant expect a great battery life but i think 2 to 2.5 hours is too short for battery time, even more doing light stuff.

Is there any way to improve the battery life or this is the more i'll get of it??

Comment: 3 cell....  Can you get a 6 or 9 cell for it? You will gain most by using the Intel graphics card though. I have a 17 inch hp omen. 5 hours on gtx 1050 and 9 on Intel with Ubuntu budgie

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if you have all correct drivers installed.
2. Install CPUFreq Indicator, It lets you control your system’s CPU speed. There are 2 modes: **Performance** and **Powersave**. You can select via the option on the top right corner of the screen.

```
    sudo apt install indicator-cpufreq
```

3. Install PowerTop

```
    sudo apt-get install powertop
```

Run it a few times (not connected to charging adapter) for calibration. These readings are PowerTop checks how much power is used by components like screen, using all cores, using wifi etc. and gives you a set of readings which you can inspect as to what is draining up battery. In Tables, `Bad` indicates a setting that’s not saving power, although it might be good for performance. `Good` indicates a power-saving setting is in effect.

4. Install TLP

TLP has several capabilities of both the tools mentioned above in terms of managing power settings. It lets you do a lot of things with power management by tweaking the settings. Also, refer to the [TLP Power settings and configurations documentation](https://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html)

---

**Some tips**
    Keep screen brightness lowest possible yet visible. Keep Bluetooth and Wifi Off unless needed. Connect an ethernet wire if need be. See what processes are running in background on startup. Disable unnecessary processes.